# Firestore query - orderBy using timestamp returning null queryDocumentSnapshots

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch all the 'posts' documents which have universityId equal to the ids present in the universityIDs list.

I want to  sort these posts in order of their timestamp(i.e "createdAt). So I used orderBy in my query but I'm getting queryDocumentSnapshot as null.
I'm getting the results if i remove the orderBy part. Can any of you guys help me on this one?

```
  firebaseFirestore.collection("posts")
                    .whereIn("universityId",universityIDs)
                    .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .addSnapshotListener( new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            Log.d("Check","Snapshot listener");

                            if(queryDocumentSnapshots == null){
                                Log.d("ISNULL","NULL");
                            }
                            else{
                                //
                            }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `queryDocumentSnapshots` is null, that means `e` is definitely not null, and it will contain a message indicating what the problem is.  You should always check this case and at *least* log the exception object so you can see what went wrong.  In this specific case, the error message will tell you that you can't order the results by a different field on which you have an "IN" query.  This is a [limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) of Firestore and there is no way to work around this in a single query.  From the linked documentation:

> You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or `in` clause.

Your whereIn filter is considered an `in` clause.

What you will have to do instead is sort the results in the client app code.

Comment: Thanks so much!This just  saved the day.The exception method had a link to creatanswered 18 hours ago

Doug Stevenson
161k1515 gold badges191191 silver badges219219 bronze badges
e indexes for composite query. After opening the link it asks the person to create the indexex.Took a few minutes to build and then i was able to fetch all my data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing